# ViewBag in JQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I am using `ViewBag` value as follows :

```
var date = "@ViewBag.fromDateForEditMode"
$('#FromDate').val(date);
```

All I am getting is `@ViewBag.fromDateForEditMode` and no value.

Comment: Stupid questions: 1. Is this within a view, not a .js file? 2. Is this within a Razor view?

Comment: @SteveWilkes : Well nobody is as intelligent as you :). This is in HTML view. Not in Razor.

Comment: Ah, ok - well the Razor engine doesn't execute when MVC is rendering an HTML file, so nothing will parse `@ViewBag.fromDateForEditMode` and replace it with the `ViewBag` property value.

Comment: @SteveWilkes : Don't know how. Please help.

Comment: @SteveWilkes isn't saying your question is stupid.  Its a common phrase asking for forgiveness if the question he is about to ask is foolish, silly, etc.

Comment: Ah, yeah - I meant my questions were stupid. Oops :)

Comment: @SteveWilkes : I am really sorry I misunderstood your comment. My apologies :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Razor engine doesn't execute when MVC is rendering an HTML file, so nothing will parse `@ViewBag.fromDateForEditMode` and replace it with the `ViewBag` property value :)

Comment: How is the content of your HTML file included in your view?

Comment: How does that matter? Just replace what are suggesting in my code : var date = "@ViewBag.fromDateForEditMode"

Comment: I matters because in order for MVC to replace `@ViewBag.fromDateForEditMode` with the appropriate value it has to be rendered within a .cshtml Razor view. How your HTML file is being included relates to whether you'll be able to do that.

Answer (score -1):

The problem that you are having is that you are trying to enclose the @ViewBag.fromDateForEditMode in quotes.  When you do that within your jquery function, this causes the browser jquery processor to evaluate it as a literal string at the time the script is called, rather than allowing your razor engine to evaluate the ViewBag contents at the time the page is loaded.

To get around this issue, use:

var startDate = new Date(@ViewBag.StartDate.Year.ToString(), @ViewBag.StartDate.Month.ToString() -1, @ViewBag.StartDate.Day.ToString());

This will allow the razor engine to evaluate the ViewBag contents before the jquery script is executed.

Comment: You must include -1 for the month value, because for some reason, the jquery new Date(year, month, day) function uses a zero based month value...

Comment: See the comments in the question. OP admits that they were trying to render a ViewBag via a simple HTML page and not a a .cshtml or Razor view.

Comment: Ah... I see that.  However, even if OP was using a .cshtml or Razor view, the posted code would still not work.  I found this OP trying to include a date value from viewbag to jquery on .cshtml.  Transferring a date value from ViewBag to a jquery script is still problematic, even if the script is being rendered in a .cshtml or Razor view.

Although my solution does not solve the problem as clarified in the comments to the OP, it DOES solve the problem that the uncommented OP had posed.  For that reason, it may be useful to someone who finds the OP, and therefore does not deserve a downgrade.